# ionic native diagnostic - how to know when the user has come back to the app

Tags: ionic-framework, location, ionic3, diagnostics

In my Ionic application I ask the user to enable location through this code:

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Posizione',
  message: 'Abilita il GPS per localizzare la tua posizione.',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'No',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Sì',
      handler: () => {
        this.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();

        }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
```

I'm looking for a way to know when the user has exited location settings and went back to the app, so that I can call the method geolocate, that otherwise is called only when the user opens the page. So at the moment he would have to go to another page and then back to the one with geolocation to locate himself. I don't know, does a kind of a callback exist? Or is there another way to call immediately geolocate after closing the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Platform.resume of ionic 2 as explained [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#resume).

> The resume event emits when the native platform pulls the application
>   out from the background. This event would emit when a Cordova app
>   comes out from the background, however, it would not fire on a
>   standard web browser.